# JS: Emptiness of Object of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, is-empty

**How to check is empty object of objects?**

The structure of object:

```
{
    order: [],
    search: [],
    where: {
        practices: [],
        role: [],
        status: []
    }
}
```

**What I tried**

```
$(object).length
```

Returns 1

```
$.isEmptyObject(filterOptions)
```

Returns false

Comment: What do you mean by empty object? An object that doesn't have any key-value pair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an empty object since it has three properties and the `where` property also has three nested properties.

If you want to know if all the properties and nested properties are empty arrays then I would do this:

```js
var isEmpty = function(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).every(function(key) {
    if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
      return obj[key].length === 0;
    } else {
      return isEmpty(obj[key]);
    }
  })
};

var obj = {
  order: [],
  search: [],
  where: {
    practices: [],
    role: [],
    status: [],
    x: {
      y: {
        z: []
      }
    }
  }
};

console.log(isEmpty(obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this also

```
function isEmpty (obj) {
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (Array.isArray(obj[key]) && obj[key].length != 0) {
       return false;
    } else if (typeof obj[key] == "object") {
        isEmpty(obj[key])
  }
  return true
}
}
```